# Same code but different output

Tags: java, input

First i want user to input somethings(name,contact,idnumber),and i will show 2 different file but code are same.The first code problem is "name" input place disappear,and the second but doesn't disappear.Can anyone tell me the problem?Im new in java.

```
public class Admin {
static Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
static Client client = new Client();
    public void admin(){
        newClient []nc = new newClient[10]; 
        \\login();
     while(true){
        System.out.println("Select 1:add Client\n 2:add Account\n 3:login as Client");
        try{
        int selection = scan.nextInt();
        switch(selection)
        {
        case 1: addClient(nc);
                break;
        case 2: \\addAccount(nc);
                break;  
        case 3: ;
                break;
        default: System.out.println("INvalid selection");
        }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ex){
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
         scan.nextLine();
            }
        }    
    } 
    public void addClient(newClient []nc){
    for(int i=0;i<nc.length;i++){
    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter contact");
    String contact = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter id number");
    String idNumber = scan.nextLine();
    nc[i]=new newClient(name,contact,idNumber);
    System.out.println(nc[i]);
    }
    }
```

Output of the first code is

Enter name

Enter contact

Why the name input place is missing?
There are the second code

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<nc.length;i++){
    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter contact");
    String contact = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter id number");
    String idNumber = scan.nextLine();
    nc[i]=new newClient(name,contact,idNumber);
    System.out.println(nc[i]);
    }
    }
```

The second code is working correctly.

Enter name

Enter contact

Enter idNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two pieces of code are in fact different.

In the second code, the `scan` object is a brand new one. And the only method you call is `nextLine()`. In the first code, the `scan` object is created an class level, and *has been used* before `addClient` is called.

"Has been used" here is very important. By that I mean you called `nextInt` on `scan` and then `nextLine`:

```
    int selection = scan.nextInt(); <-- You called nextInt here!
    switch(selection)
    {
    case 1: addClient(nc);
            break;
    case 2: \\addAccount(nc);
            break;  
    case 3: ;
            break;
    default: System.out.println("INvalid selection");
    }
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException ex){
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
     scan.nextLine();
        }
    }    
} 
public void addClient(newClient []nc){
    for(int i=0;i<nc.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter name");
        String name = scan.nextLine(); <-- then you called nextLine here!
        System.out.println("Enter contact");
        String contact = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter id number");
        String idNumber = scan.nextLine();
        nc[i]=new newClient(name,contact,idNumber);
        System.out.println(nc[i]);
    }
}
```

This makes the `nextLine` method return an empty string.

> Why?

Let's look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for both `nextInt` and `nextLine`:

> nextInt()
>
> Scans the next token of the input as an int.
>
> nextLine()
>
> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

I have created a simpler code that reproduces this situation to explain why calling `nextLine` immediately after `nextInt` can cause problems:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
s.nextInt();
System.out.println(s.nextLine());
```

I will use a `|` character to denote where the scanner's current position is.

When the program starts,

```
|
```

Then I enter the number 20:

```
|20
```

Now the scanner reads the 20, according the documetation, the scanner should be at this position:

```
20|
```

Here comes the interesting part, `nextLine` "Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped."

```
20
|
```

So what input has the scanner skipped? Nothing! As a result, an empty string is returned.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, I've learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

as `ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ` says `scan.nextInt` wouldnt read the `enter`.

---

so an alternative solution is before read `name contact id` information, employ `scan.nextLine()` to read the `enter` like this:

```
public void addClient(newClient []nc){
    scan.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<nc.length;i++){
       ....// your origin code
    }
```